# Is there any way to skip Android device setup wizard using ADB when device is on Android P?

Tags: android, python, adb

I want to skip the Android P setup wizard programmatically to reach Home Screen to proceed doing other scripted jobs. Since the ADB already recognizes the device when plugged on first setup wizard page, I was trying to skip initial setup using it. Is there any way to do that using ADB or by other tools, potentially Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have tried this before and I don't believe there is. While the ADB recognizes that there is a device attached, that doesn't mean it can read it. The device would have to be set up completely before it would be able to interact and read/send data to the ADB.